# Possible to use linear regression instead of paired t test?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear, paired-data

I have participants who were measured two times. First, without any intervention. And second, with an intervention. Thus, I should use paired t-test as both measurements are normally distributed (controlled with Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and eyeballing(plotting)).

But how to replace this test with a linear regression? The following approach isn't correct as both groups include the same participants? Any other modelling options (multilevel etc)?

```
y ~ group
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A paired t-test is a test of whether the mean *difference between conditions* among individuals is different from 0. (It doesn't require normal distributions of the individual measurements among participants in either condition individually, so your K-S test and plots weren't really needed.) A normal distribution of the *differences* among individuals is assumed for standard significance tests, but [other tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) can be performed if that assumption is untenable.

So if you have single pre- and post-intervention measurements on all individuals, you can simply model

```
(postValue - preValue) ~ 1
```

to put this in a linear regression context. That will, however, just give you the same result as the standard paired t-test.